# PHP Call to a member function on a non-object -> Classes

Tags: php, class

I want my script to read a file and create classes, then I want it to read the exact same file again so it makes changes to those classes according to what the file says. But I'm getting an error on the second While: Call to a member function getlasttrade() on a non-object.

```
  <?php

include ("Ideia.php");

$handle = @fopen("C:\Users\A\Desktop\Projecto ES/input.txt", "r");

if ($handle) {
    $booleanuser = FALSE;

    while (!feof($handle)) {

        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        $partial = substr($buffer, 0, 4);
        $nomeuser;
        $iduser;
        $saldo = substr($buffer, 0, 5);
        $portefolio = substr($buffer, 0, 9);
        $nomeportefolio;
        $posicaoigual = strpos($buffer, "=");

        //-------CRIA O USER----------//
        if ($partial == "user") {
            $booleanuser = TRUE;
            $nomeuser=substr($buffer, 0, 5);
            $iduser=substr($buffer, 4);
            $nomeuser = new User($iduser);
        }

        if ($booleanuser == FALSE) {
            //-------CRIA A IDEIA----------//
            if ($partial == "idea") {
                $nomeideia=substr($buffer, 0, 5);
                $idideia=substr($buffer, 4, $posicaoigual-5);
                $nomeideia = new Ideia($idideia, substr($buffer, $posicaoigual+1));
                }
        }

        if ($booleanuser == TRUE){
            //-------ADICIONA O SALDO AO USER----------//
            if ($saldo == "Saldo"){
                $nomeuser->addsaldo(substr($buffer, 7));
            //echo $nomeuser->greetuser();  
            }

        //-------CRIA O PORTEFOLIO----------//
            if ($portefolio == "Portfolio"){
                $nomeportefolio="portefolio".$iduser;
                $nomeportefolio = new Portefolio($iduser,$iduser);
            }

        //------ADICIONA AS IDEIAS AO PORTEFOLIO----------//
            if ($partial == "idea"){
                $nomeportefolio->addideiasportefolio("0",substr($buffer, 4, 1), substr($buffer, $posicaoigual+1));
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}



$letakeover = @fopen("C:\Users\Bia\Desktop\Projecto ES/input.txt", "r");
if ($letakeover) {
//-----------------------------------TAKEOVER-----------------------------------//

        //$nomeideia="idea1";
        //echo $nomeideia->getlasttrade(1);

    while (!feof($letakeover)) {

        $buffer = fgets($letakeover, 4096);
        $posicaoigual = strpos($buffer, "=");
        $idideia=substr($buffer, 4, $posicaoigual-5);
        $nomeideia = substr($buffer, $posicaoigual+1);

        echo $nomeideia->getlasttrade($idideia);
        echo "ola";     
    }

    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

If i write the function here it echos the right thing. Can someone help?

```
    if ($partial == "idea") {
        $nomeideia=substr($buffer, 0, 5);
        $idideia=substr($buffer, 4, $posicaoigual-5);
        $nomeideia = new Ideia($idideia, substr($buffer, $posicaoigual+1));
        //echo $nomeideia->getlasttrade($idideia);
    }
```

Comment: **FYI**, you are being redundant doing this: `if ($booleanuser == TRUE){}`, just use `if ($booleanuser){}` or for "if false" use `if (!$booleanuser){}`

Answer (score 3):

Your first `$nomeideia` is an object:

```
$nomeideia = new Ideia($idideia, substr($buffer, $posicaoigual+1))
```

Your second, is **clearly** not:

```
$nomeideia = substr($buffer, $posicaoigual+1);
```

Either you got confused with variables (using two with the same name) or you overlooked something.

I can't tell you if you need to use a new Idea object for the second case too, though, as I do not know what your code does, but the error is clearly there.

I guess it's the same as the first one, since they look pretty similar.

Comment: I want to call a function inside the class $nomeideia, but I don't want to call it at the moment i create that class, I want to call it later. Am I being confusing?

Comment: $later what? You're **assigning a new value** to the variable, PHP is not strongly typed so it will accept it gladly even if previously the same variable was holding another type (object). You might rename the "temp" variable holding the substr() result

Comment: Just want to call it later, later in time :p

Comment: ...forget the "later", did you read the rest of my comment? :)

Comment: Yes, I am gonna try doing it differently, inside the first while. I was hoping doing $nomeideia = somestring I could do somestring->function, but I understand I can't do that.